# How to calculate final velocity of a moving object emitting EM radiation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, kinematics, momentum

An object/system with rest mass 2 kg is travelling at the speed of 1 m/sec in a straight line. Its kinetic energy is 1 Joules. At some instance of time, it emits photons in the same direction having total energy of 1 Joules without any change in its rest mass (I assume that is possible). What will the final velocity of the object/system be?

Assuming conservation of energy system after emitting 1 joule of energy must come to a rest? Is that correct?

If not can someone please explain why not? And how much energy it has to emit to come to a stop (we are assuming mass doesn't change)?

Comment: can someone please comment ?